# EC2 root device type and charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have just created my first EC2 instance 2 days ago and had some questions about its charging against root device. Currently, the root device is EBS type with 4000 IOPS. This device is reliable but it is over my budget (about $10 per day, even when I shutdown the instance), since my site is under the developing mode at this moment. So my questions:

1. If I stay with EBS type root device, any suggestions on how to lower its cost (e.g. switch to standard EBS)?
2. Should I use regular instance-store root device? What is the cost for this selection?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are using provisioned IOPS. This is optional and it sounds like you don't actually need it.

Comment: @datasage: I have the same feeling. So I should switch to instance-store type device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using provisioned IOPS, which is an optional feature when High IO performance is needed from EBS volumes.

You wont need to switch to instance storage to avoid this cost. But you will need to re-provision the volume without provisioned IOPS to bring the cost down.

The quickest way would be to launch a new instance, but in this case, do not enable provisoned IOPS.

However, if you already have software installed on your volumes, and don't want to reinstall it. Then create a snapshot of your current volume. Use that snapshot to create a new volume without provisioned IOPS. Switch the root volume of your instance to the new volume created from a snapshot. Then delete your old volume.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I switched to a standard EBS device, will I be charged when my instance is off (currently, I have to pay that)? In addition, it seems like all the EBS device will be charged by the usage, while the instance store device are free, right?

Comment: You will pay a cost for the amount of storage you provision. As such, you shouldn't provision much more than you will be using. You will also pay a cost for I/O ops, but its unlikey that will be very high if you are only in development. Using instance store, you will loose the ability to stop the instance.

Comment: So I should shrink the size of my EBS device? How about this plan: 1. convert it to a regular EBS. 2. shrink it to 30GB from 200GB (I am using 20GB now). Will I be charged by the EBS when the instance if start/stop?

Comment: I don't think you can create a smaller volume for a snapshot of a larger volume. You will only be charge for the provisioned space (something like 10-19 cents per GB/month, depending on your region). The cost is actually billed in hourly increments based on the monthly cost.

Comment: You are right, it seems like I need to shrink the EBS in Ubuntu system...

Answer (score 1):

For starting out, I recommend you use

1. Standard EBS boot (not instance-store)
2. No EBS optimized instance
3. No Provisioned IOPS

Once you get comfortable with how EC2 works and if you run into IO bottlenecks, then you can test upgrading to EBS optimized instances and Provisioned IOPS EBS volumes. These two features work together. Use the lowest PIOPS settings that work for your application.

Once you are an expert with EC2 and are not worried about losing an instance and all its data (because you can automate the creation of new instances and you have streaming replication/backups of all your data) then you can consider using instance-store boot disks. I wrote an article about [EBS boot vs instance-store](http://alestic.com/2012/01/ec2-ebs-boot-recommended).

I would recommend you start a new  EBS boot instance from scratch without EBS optimized and without EBS Provisioned IOPS. You should work to automate this startup process so that you can easily replace an instance; there are a lot of times when this is useful as you are already finding out two days into your experience.

Comment: Thanks! Currently my instance is not an EBS optimized, and I have created an EBS device without provisioned IOPS. In this situation, will I still be charged daily from the EBS when the instance is off? Does the size of the EBS device related to the cost (currently I am using 20GB of 200GB)?

Comment: @tao.hong: Yes EBS is charged by GB/month. Please consider creating new questions on ServerFault as you learn about this, instead of asking new questions in comments.